# Rails app accumulating memory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks, ruby-on-rails-5.1

My problem is, that my Rails 5.1 app accumulates a lot of memory (until exceeding the servers limit).
Because I am not experienced in managing the momory of a rails application I wanted to ask for possible reasons of the problem or ways to test what is causing the accumulation.

[image: The metrics of my app]

*You can see on the image, that in each case after restarting the app, the used memory gets bigger and bigger.*

---

**Some information about my app:**

- it uses redis for ActionCable (without a connection yet)
- it uses sidekiq workers (but no worker performs actions yet)

---

If you need more information, please ask for it in the comments. :)